# What is the CORS origin of a deployed ionic application?

Tags: asp.net-core, ionic-framework, cors

When in development mode, I know the origin of an ionic application, but once it is deployed, what origin would I set in my API?

I have tried looking for information about this but all I have managed to find is people saying to turn off CORS in development mode, but how I would keep CORS enabled in production mode and still use my application.

I am making use of an ASP.net core API.

Comment: you can Enable CORS on your server.

Comment: I see several origins listed at the end of https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/cors for different deployment types -- do any of those match your use case?

Comment: One other thing to check: when your production code performs an HTTP request, does it include an `Origin: ...` request header? If so, you can just mirror that back in your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ...` response header.

Comment: Hello, are you still having the problem?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Yes I am. When I check the origin of the Ionic application running on my phone I see http://localhost

Comment: Glad to hear....

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron So how do I set the origin of my ionic app so that only it can have access to my API and not all Origins as I have it now?

Comment: You can set on your `API` end rather in Ionic.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron The way I see it, in my API I would set it to allow any app with the origin Localhost, or whatever I set my apps hostname to be in the ionic config. My problem was that I thought anyone would be able to use their app to access my API, but the way to combat this is to require users to sign in and get a token, and only then can they make use of the API. Am I correct with my thinking?

Comment: If so than CORS shouldn't be implemented either side, because anyone can be your user, instead authentication and authorization would be the solution.

Answer (score -1):

The origin is the URL of the site that served up your iconic app.